# Doxygen table: Create table that has line breaks in source

Tags: doxygen

```
/**
 * | A | B |
 * | - | - |
 * | 123 | This should be a long line with
 * a line break without breaking the table |
 * | A further | row |
 */
```

Doxygen stops the table parsing after "with". How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Hmm, good question. You'd have thought that dox could have coped with this, but even the underlying [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table) info on tables doesn't mention how to cope with this case.  I assume `backslash-return` at the end of the line doesn't oblige?

Comment: You're right, the backslash is parsed as a character. Sorry for not mentioning that I've already tried that.

Comment: A rather over-the-top workround is, of course, to do the table in HTML.  I must admit that most of my doxygen tables are done that way, except for really small trivial ones.

Comment: Why not use a \n or <br> in the line?

Comment: @Cheeseminer: Thanks, at least a workaround for it.
albert: I would like to have a line break in the source, not in the table itself.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using markups for table is not convinient enough. if you will switch to html fromat you will not have a problem to break whenever you want. 
I have created the following aliases in Doxyfile for my table to simplify the code:

```
"table_start_b{1}=<table><caption align= bottom>\1</caption>" \
"table_start_t{1}=<table><caption align= top>\1</caption>" \
"table_end=</table>" \
"table_h2{2}=<tr><th>\1</th><th>\2</th></tr>" \
"table_row2{2}=<tr><td align= center>\1</td><td align= center>\2</td></tr>" \
```

and use it as following :

```
\table_start_t{Abbreviations}
    \table_h2{ 
               Acronym , 
               Description }
    \table_row2{ "TBD" , "To be 
                          defined" }
\table_end
```

You have no problem to have a line break in any place.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but still possible. Is readable in markup and the end result is not that bad.

```
/**
 * | A | B |
 * | - | - |
 * | 123 | This should be a long line with
 * |     | a line break without breaking the table |
 * | A further | row |
 */
```

[image]